# RTC_RD_TIME: Invalid Argument error

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, timer, microprocessor, rtc

When I try to read hwclock date and time manually it is working fine.

```
root@nb2:~# busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r
Thu Oct 20 10:00:39 2022  0.000000 seconds
root@nb2:~# busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r
Thu Oct 20 10:00:40 2022  0.000000 seconds
root@nb2:~# busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r
Thu Oct 20 10:00:41 2022  0.000000 seconds
root@nb2:~# busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r
Thu Oct 20 10:00:41 2022  0.000000 seconds
root@nb2:~# busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 -r
```

But when I run the shell script I get `RTC_RD_TIME: Invalid Argument error`.

```
root@nb2:/opt/nb2-test-utils/rtc# ./001-rtc-test.sh 
*** rtc test ***
[ Info ] Enter the date and time string to set RTC < yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss >:
2025-06-12 12:59:59
Thu Jun 12 12:59:59 UTC 2025
[Info ] RTC set to :
hwclock: RTC_RD_TIME: Invalid argument
```

The script is below:

```
echo "[ Info ] Enter the date and time string to set RTC < yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss >:"
read DATE_AND_TIME;
date --set="${DATE_AND_TIME}"
busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc0 -w
echo "[ Info ] RTC set to :"
busybox hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc0
```

Please let me know why I get this kind of inconsistent behavior, and how the issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It appears your manual test is using `/dev/rtc1` and your script is using `/dev/rtc0`, and that may well be the cause.  (Additionally, your manual test uses `-r` and your scripted one doesn't, but this should make no difference.)

NB: you might care to add `set -e` (quit script if error) to your script to prevent early failures being ignored.  `set -x` very helpful for debugging.